# Phalcon - Create a custom auto-increment id

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to produce a custom auto-increment id. my custom auto-incerement ID should be like below...

```
MGL02021801
```

"MGL" is for City name.

"02" is for a day.

"02" is today's month

"18" is for this year's last 2 digits.

"01" is my incrementer.

The counter will go on like below ...

```
MGL02021801
MGL02021802
MGL02021803
MGL02021804
```

I have done something but didn't work. I am tired of all these. I will be glad for any suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is only work for `INT` type. If you want a id like this store city name and timestamp in separated columns.

Ex:-

```
id  |  cityname | timestamp
1   |  MGL      | 2018-02-02 11:26
```

and use `CONCAT()` when select.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`cityname`,DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%e%m%y'),LPAD(`id`,2,'0')) AS `id`  FROM `yourtable`
```

OUTPUT:-

```
MGL02021801
```

Comment: Shown `id` won't work for his idea. I think he wants every new date to start from 01.

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT is database related stuff.

You might want use trigger before insert. But i never used it to be honest - i just know that such thing exists.